# Custom Process template Workflow WorkItem BUG TFS 2012 Update 3

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

today I am in a project that you need to modify the workflow work item BUG, which should have several custom states , about seven. 
we have developed the  modification required, upload template  without problem, but create proyect with custom template send error.
The information in internet is very diffuse and have not found a solution. 
your help will be invaluable.

Thank you.

1) Download Process template Manager

2) Create new Process Template name DIBAM QA

3) Modify file CommonConfiguration.xml and workflow BUG WorkItem

4) Upload  Folder Process Template

5) Create TEamProject Custom template Error: TF400506

DIBAM QA\WorkItem Tracking\Process\CommonConfiguration.xml

```
<State type="Proposed" value="Proposed" />
       <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
       <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
       <State type="Resolved" value="Resolved" />

       <State type="Proposed" value="Nuevo" />
       <State type="Proposed" value="Sugerencia" />
       <State type="InProgress" value="Asignado" />
       <State type="InProgress" value="Rechazado" />
       <State type="InProgress" value="En Proceso" />
       <State type="InProgress" value="ReAsignado" />
       <State type="Complete" value="Cerrado" />
       <State type="Resolved" value="Resuelto" />
```

\DIBAM QA\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\BUG.xml

```
<WORKFLOW>
  <STATES>
    <STATE value="Asignado">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="En Proceso">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Resuelto">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Cerrado">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
          <READONLY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Nuevo">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Rechazado">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Sugerencia">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <REQUIRED />
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
  </STATES>
  <TRANSITIONS>
    <TRANSITION from="" to="Nuevo">
      <REASONS>
        <REASON value="Compilado Fallido" />
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Defecto reportado" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <DEFAULT from="currentuser" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Asignado" to="En Proceso">
      <ACTIONS>
        <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork" />
      </ACTIONS>
      <REASONS>
        <REASON value="Investigate" />
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Approved" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="En Proceso" to="Asignado">
      <ACTIONS>
        <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork" />
      </ACTIONS>
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Investigation Complete" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="En Proceso" to="Resuelto">
      <ACTIONS>
        <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin" />
      </ACTIONS>
      <REASONS>
        <REASON value="Cannot Reproduce">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Cannot Reproduce" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
                <LISTITEM value="Cannot Reproduce" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="Deferred">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Deferred" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
                <LISTITEM value="Deferred" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="Duplicate">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Duplicate" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
                <LISTITEM value="Duplicate" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="As Designed">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="As Designed" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
                <LISTITEM value="As Designed" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="Obsolete">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Obsolete" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
                <LISTITEM value="Obsolete" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="Copied to Backlog">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Copied to Backlog" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
                <LISTITEM value="Copied to Backlog" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Fixed">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Fixed" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
                <LISTITEM value="Fixed" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </DEFAULTREASON>
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
          <COPY from="value" value="Fixed" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Resuelto" to="En Proceso">
      <REASONS>
        <REASON value="Test Failed" />
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Not fixed" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <COPY from="field" field="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Resuelto" to="Cerrado">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Verificado" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Asignado" to="Cerrado">
      <REASONS>
        <REASON value="Deferred" />
        <REASON value="Duplicate" />
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Rejected" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Cerrado" to="En Proceso">
      <REASONS>
        <REASON value="Regression" />
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Closed in Error" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <COPY from="field" field="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Nuevo" to="Asignado">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Defecto reportado" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Asignado" to="Rechazado">
      <REASONS>
        <REASON value="Duplicada" />
        <REASON value="Fuera de alcance" />
        <DEFAULTREASON value="No es una incidencia" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Nuevo" to="Sugerencia">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Fuera de alcance" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Rechazado" to="Cerrado">
      <REASONS>
        <REASON value="Fuera de alcance" />
        <REASON value="Duplicada" />
        <DEFAULTREASON value="No es una incidencia" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Rechazado" to="Sugerencia">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Fuera de alcance" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
  </TRANSITIONS>
</WORKFLOW>
```

https://imageshack.com/i/p6ed2761p

https://imageshack.com/i/f0e39567p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have states in your CommonProcessConfig that do not exist in your Bug work item.

Based on the CommonProcessConfig in your question, your Bug must have all of the following states - otherwise you must either edit your Bug WITD or the CommonProcessConfig:

- Proposed
- Active
- Closed
- Resolved
- Nuevo
- Sugerencia
- Asignado
- Rechazado
- En Proceso
- ReAsignado
- Cerrado
- Resuelto